# Read incoming sms without spaces

Tags: blackberry, sms

The following code reads an incoming sms then prints the body of the message. How do I get the app to print out the message without any spaces inbetween?

For example: The incoming sms reads "Here I am", so "Here I am" is printed out, but I want the app to print out "HereIam".

How can I do this? Any help would be most appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public void run() {
 try {
 DatagramConnection _dc = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://"); 
   for(;;) { 
    Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength()); 
    _dc.receive(d); 
    byte[] bytes = d.getData();
    String address = d.getAddress(); 
    String msg = new String(bytes); 
    System.out.println(address);
    System.out.println(msg);
   } 

 }catch (Exception me) { 

 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

add this line to code

```
System.out.println(replaceAll(msg," ",""));
```

Add this method as well

```
  public static String replaceAll(String source, String pattern,
        String replacement) {
    if (source == null)
        return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int idx = -1;
    int patIdx = 0;

    while ((idx = source.indexOf(pattern, patIdx)) != -1) {
        sb.append(source.substring(patIdx, idx));
        sb.append(replacement);
        patIdx = idx + pattern.length();
    }

    sb.append(source.substring(patIdx));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It replaces all the spaces with empty string, which is what you want.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but where do you add the method? Inside public void run() or outside? I tried running the method inside public void run() and it gives me an error, but if I run it outside then the app dorsn't recognize the method.

Comment: You add a method implementation, outside of a method. Please add it outside, and post the error you are getting.

Comment: I can't post the code because its too long to add as a comment, but the error I get when I run the method outside public void run is

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.0.0\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=Messaging Messaging.rapc  import=..\..\lib\net_rim_api.jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.0.0\bin\Nr\first.java" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.0.0\bin\Nr\last.java"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 7.0.0\bin\Nr\last.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol: method ReplaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                    String msg2 = (ReplaceAll(msg, " ",""));
                                   ^

Comment: It cannot find your ReplaceAll method . Is it replaceAll or ReplaceAll??

Comment: I got it right now, I wrote the method wrong, wrote ReplaceAll instead of replaceAll, silly me. Thanks for the help rfsk2010.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
msg = msg.replace("\s+", "");
```

Comment: Sorry this wont work as this method is not available in String class in BB java. check http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html. more over there is no support for Regex in BB java.

Comment: Whoops! Didn't realise the platform was handicapped :(

Comment: lol. Been living with the platform for quite some time. its dying a slow death